# Jupyter notebook not opening in browser

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook version : 4.3.1
I created a new environment and installed jupyter notebook in it, after starting notebook using command `jupyter notebook`, I am getting the following output and on trying to open then link in browser gives the following output.

[image]

```
(tflearn) C:\Users\himan\DLND\Week2\sentiment-analysis>jupyter notebook
[I 07:22:07.563 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\himan\DLND\Week2\sentiment-analysis
[I 07:22:07.563 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 07:22:07.563 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/?token=2ece159979892d1e04be5e2db2ff06c479f75faba3dc1e02
[I 07:22:07.563 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 07:22:07.569 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=2ece159979892d1e04be5e2db2ff06c479f75faba3dc1e02
```

Earlier everything worked fine, but recently this started, I tried using different port like 8889, 8890 and after 2 or three runs they also stop working.
I am using anaconda on windows 10.

I tried similar questions but they are not working for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried connecting to http://localhost:8888/ without the token?

Comment: @timleathart yes I have tried, it gives the same screen in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

conda update nb_conda nb_conda_kernels nb_anacondacloud